# Login screen reappears after login

Tags: kde

I am on Fedora 16 KDE spin. Yesterday I ran the `fsck` command and that broke things. I can login via the tty, so I guess it has nothing to do with the shadow file. The login screen reappears after login no matter how many times I try to get past it. The permissions are the same as before. Also I have tried renaming the .kde folder. Doesn't help. This affects all the users, even root. My guess is the X server is restarting after login bringing me back to the login screen. Any way I can solve this?

Comment: I think you should start by looking at `~/.xsession-errors` and `/var/log/messages`

Comment: also `/var/log/Xorg.1.log`

Comment: Can you log in if you do `single` user mode?  If you can't then your `/etc/shadow` file might be borked.

Comment: You can also try to start X from sommand line with `startx` optionally redirecting its stdout and stderr: `startx 2>startx.err 1>startx.log`

Comment: sorry for the late reply. It was the X server indeed. I followed what peterph said and the startx.err file had this, 

`/usr/bin/ssh-agent: error while loading shared libraries: libfipscheck.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
xinit: connection to X server lost.`

I have no idea what that means. I tried disabling ssh but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your answers in the comments, the problem is that the program "ssh-agent" can't load the library libfipscheck which it needs in order to run. The quick fix is to edit your .xinitrc file and comment out the call to ssh-agent from it. The real fix is to re-install the package fipscheck-lib .

Comment: Amazing! That did the trick. It was the `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc-common` file that had the SSH-AGENT line.