# Cannot login into XFCE screen blink and return back to login screen

Tags: debian, xorg, xfce, openssl, lightdm-gtk-greeter

Recently a kernel upgrade to 4.19.0-5amd64 broke my desktop environment and produced other problems, some of them I already asked here - [Unmet broken dependencies debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533871/unmet-broken-dependencies-debian) and [radeon failed vce resume after upgrade to newest Linux kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533842/radeon-failed-vce-resume-after-upgrade-to-newest-linux-kernel).

Those are now resolved, but other issues remain. When I installed xfce4 with lightdm on the system, I cannot move past the login screen. I know there are 
 related topics ([Login screen reappears after login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55176/login-screen-reappears-after-login), [Screen blanks at login screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208091/screen-blanks-at-login-screen), ...) here but they didn't help me much.

Suspicious messages found in log files:

1. `$HOME/.xsession-errors`

> OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1010102f, you have 1010000f

2. var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log

> ** (lightdm-gtk-greeter:719): WARNING ** [PIDs] Failed to execute command upstart

At same time I can login to *tty*. Also, my user is in *tty* group. I tried to remove *.Xauthority* file - nothing changed.

What might be a reason of that I cannot login? Any ideas how I can fix it?

Here is full content of some log files.

**/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log**

```
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.26.0, UID=0 PID=682
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Registered seat module local
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.21s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.21s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.21s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.21s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.21s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.34s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.34s] DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
[+0.34s] DEBUG: Could not run plymouth --ping: Failed to execute child process “plymouth” (No such file or directory)
[+0.34s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.34s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.34s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.35s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.35s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Launching X Server
[+0.43s] DEBUG: Launching process 694: /usr/bin/X :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.44s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.44s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.44s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.84s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.84s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1001 added
[+1.82s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+1.83s] DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (automatic reaping requested) (fd close requested) 
[+9.21s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 694
[+9.21s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Got signal from X server :0
[+9.21s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+9.24s] DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) (child_setup specified) 
[+9.24s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+9.24s] DEBUG: Session pid=737: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'lightdm'
[+9.40s] DEBUG: Session pid=737: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+9.40s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+9.40s] DEBUG: Session pid=737: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter
[+9.40s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm/data/lightdm
[+9.40s] DEBUG: Session pid=737: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log
[+10.18s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+10.18s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c1
[+10.18s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c1
[+10.18s] DEBUG: Session c1 is already active
[+12.22s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.26.0 api=1 resettable=false
[+14.64s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication
[+14.64s] DEBUG: Session pid=782: Started with service 'lightdm', username '(null)'
[+14.70s] DEBUG: Session pid=782: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+14.70s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+26.03s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for slesh
[+26.03s] DEBUG: Session pid=782: Sending SIGTERM
[+26.03s] DEBUG: Session pid=784: Started with service 'lightdm', username 'slesh'
[+26.03s] DEBUG: Session pid=782: Terminated with signal 15
[+26.03s] DEBUG: Session: Failed during authentication
[+26.03s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+26.05s] DEBUG: Session pid=784: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+26.05s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+32.28s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+32.31s] DEBUG: Session pid=784: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+32.31s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user slesh: Success
[+32.31s] DEBUG: User slesh authorized
[+32.32s] DEBUG: Greeter sets language en_US.utf8
[+32.40s] DEBUG: Greeter requests session lightdm-xsession
[+32.40s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping greeter; display server will be re-used for user session
[+32.40s] DEBUG: Terminating login1 session c1
[+32.41s] DEBUG: Session pid=737: Sending SIGTERM
[+32.57s] DEBUG: Greeter closed communication channel
[+32.57s] DEBUG: Session pid=737: Exited with return value 0
[+32.57s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+32.57s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Greeter stopped, running session
[+32.57s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
[+32.57s] DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) (child_setup specified) 
[+32.57s] DEBUG: Session pid=784: Running command /etc/X11/Xsession default
[+32.57s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm/data/slesh
[+32.57s] DEBUG: Session pid=784: Logging to .xsession-errors
[+32.74s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+32.74s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session 2
[+32.74s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to 
[+32.74s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to 2
[+32.74s] DEBUG: Session 2 is already active
[+34.10s] DEBUG: Session pid=784: Exited with return value 255
[+34.10s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+34.10s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+34.10s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 694
[+34.12s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to 
[+35.23s] DEBUG: Process 694 exited with return value 0
[+35.23s] DEBUG: XServer 0: X server stopped
[+35.23s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+35.23s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+35.23s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+35.23s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Active display server stopped, starting greeter
[+35.23s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+35.23s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+35.23s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+35.23s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+35.23s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+35.23s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+35.23s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Launching X Server
[+35.23s] DEBUG: Launching process 836: /usr/bin/X :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+35.23s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+35.97s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 836
[+35.97s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Got signal from X server :0
[+35.97s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+36.00s] DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) (child_setup specified) 
[+36.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+36.00s] DEBUG: Session pid=851: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'lightdm'
[+36.03s] DEBUG: Session pid=851: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+36.03s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+36.03s] DEBUG: Session pid=851: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter
[+36.03s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm/data/lightdm
[+36.03s] DEBUG: Session pid=851: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log
[+36.06s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+36.06s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c2
[+36.06s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c2
[+36.06s] DEBUG: Session c2 is already active
[+36.17s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.26.0 api=1 resettable=false
[+36.40s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication
[+36.40s] DEBUG: Session pid=867: Started with service 'lightdm', username '(null)'
[+36.41s] DEBUG: Session pid=867: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+36.41s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+52.16s] DEBUG: Got signal 15 from process 1
[+52.16s] DEBUG: Caught Terminated signal, shutting down
[+52.16s] DEBUG: Stopping display manager
[+52.16s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping
[+52.16s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server
[+52.16s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 836
[+52.16s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping session
[+52.16s] DEBUG: Terminating login1 session c2
[+52.21s] DEBUG: Session pid=851: Sending SIGTERM
[+52.21s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping session
[+52.21s] DEBUG: Session pid=867: Sending SIGTERM
[+52.21s] DEBUG: Session pid=867: Terminated with signal 15
[+52.21s] DEBUG: Session: Failed during authentication
[+52.21s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+52.45s] DEBUG: Greeter closed communication channel
[+52.45s] DEBUG: Session pid=851: Exited with return value 0
[+52.45s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+52.46s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to 
[+53.22s] DEBUG: Process 836 exited with return value 0
[+53.22s] DEBUG: XServer 0: X server stopped
[+53.22s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+53.22s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+53.22s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+53.22s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopped
[+53.22s] DEBUG: Display manager stopped
[+53.22s] DEBUG: Stopping daemon
[+53.22s] DEBUG: Exiting with return value 0
```

**/var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log**

```
** Message: 16:44:27.363: Starting lightdm-gtk-greeter 2.0.6 (Dec 27 2018, 16:15:47)
** Message: 16:44:27.364: [Configuration] Reading file: /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.d/01_debian.conf
** Message: 16:44:27.364: [Configuration] Reading file: /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf

** (lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): WARNING **: 16:44:27.460: [PIDs] Failed to execute command: upstart

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:27.675: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:37.582: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:40.964: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:40.994: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:41.017: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:41.032: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:41.051: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:41.066: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:41.082: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:41.098: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:41.115: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:41.858: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:41.874: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:41.890: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:854): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:43.397: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node menubar owner GreeterMenuBar)
Gdk-Message: 16:44:43.424: lightdm-gtk-greeter: Fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server :0.
```

**/var/log/lightdm/x-0.log**

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux debian 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-5+deb10u2 (2019-08-08) x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-5-amd64 root=UUID=d666ae35-4c82-44d3-bf21-0c2b4f4fd21b ro quiet
Build Date: 05 March 2019  08:11:12PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Aug 11 16:44:26 2019
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(II) AMDGPU(G0): [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
(II) modeset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

**.xsession-errors**

```
Xsession: X session started for slesh at Sun 11 Aug 2019 04:44:24 PM +03
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/slesh/.Xauthority
localuser:slesh being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=slesh
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANGUAGE=en_US:en
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/slesh
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=lightdm-xsession
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=slesh
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDM_LANG=en_US.utf8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=lightdm-xsession
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/slesh/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm/data/slesh
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDMSESSION=lightdm-xsession
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/slesh
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1010102f, you have 1010000f
```

Comment: I finally pass login screen just removing openssh-client. But problem with OpenSSh version mismatch still present so my [dhclient doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535072/dhclient-openssl-1-1-1)

Comment: I have this problem too! :( I purged xfce, yet I still see `DEBUG: Seat seat0: Failed to find session configuration xfce` in lightdm.log